# "setspn -s" vs. "setspn -a"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, kerberos, spn

According to the [Setspn Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc773257(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it's discouraged to use `Setspn -A` to add an SPN record and it's suggested to use `Setspn -S` instead.

It's said that `Setspn -S` checks if SPN already exists before adding a new one. `Setspn –A` does not perform this check.

> Although you can use Setspn -A to add an SPN, you should use Setspn -S
> instead because -S will verify that there are no duplicate SPNs.

However on Windows Server 2012 I see that `Setspn -S` and `Setspn -A` behave in the same way: if an SPN record for an account exists then I get a failure both with `-A` and `-S` arguments.

**Is there any real difference between `Setspn -S` and `Setspn -A`?**

Comment: Nice extra documentation as now the `setspn` documentation does not even mention the `-a` argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not any more.  You sort of answered your own question.  It has obviously been decided that there's no need for the original -A functionality of *not* checking for duplicates any more... but you can't just go willy-nilly ripping the -A out, because someone's script somewhere that was using -A would break.

Adding some official documentation to back up my claim:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831747.aspx

> Changes to SetSPN
>
> ---
>
> In Windows Server 2012, SetSPN will no longer be able to register
>   duplicate SPNs in a domain. When SetSPN –a is used, SetSPN will treat
>   it as SetSPN –s.
>
> For eveloping information about SetSPN, see Service Principal Names
>   (SPNs) SetSPN Syntax (Setspn.exe) on the TechNet Wiki. For the command
>   reference, see Setspn in the TechNet Library.

Comment: +1 for the use of *willy-nilly* in an SO answer ;)